# How to get VSCode to use Prettier for HTML and not JS in Vue files

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, prettier

My team is using VS Code for a Vue project.
We like the Prettier formatting for HTML but not for Javascript.

How can I configure VS Code to use Prettier for one language and not another, within .vue files that contain both languages?

I have tried this:

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
"[javascript]": {
   "editor.formatOnSave": false,
   "editor.defaultFormatter": null
}
```

but the javascript is still formatted to Prettier rules on save.

and I have tried this, but then the HTML is not formatted to Prettier rules:

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"[html]": {
   "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
"[javascript]": {
   "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
}
```